# php array output data using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, iteration

I'd like to set the following up as a loop (so that the pattern is repeated every 5 elements). I've tried to read up on it and I believe I need to set it up as an array, but I have no idea where to start.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="ccm-page-list">

    <?php

        $i= 0;i;
        foreach ($pages as $page):
            $i++;

            $title  = $th->entities($page->getCollectionName());
            $url    = $nh->getLinkToCollection($page);
            $target = ($page->getCollectionPointerExternalLink() != '' && $page->openCollectionPointerExternalLinkInNewWindow()) ? '_blank' : $page->getAttribute('nav_target');
            $target = empty($target) ? '_self' : $target;

            $description = $page->getCollectionDescription();
            $description = $controller->truncateSummaries ? $th->shorten($description, $controller->truncateChars) : $description;
            $description = $th->entities($description); 

            $img   = $page->getAttribute('thumbnail');
            $thumb = $ih->getThumbnail($img, 550, 550, true);

    ?>

    <a href="<?php  echo $url ?>" target="<?php  echo $target ?>"> <div class="col-sm-4  grid-item">
        <div class="item-img-blog" >
            <img src="<?php  echo $thumb->src ?>" width="auto" height="100%" alt="" />
            <div <?php 
                if($i == 1) {
                ?>class="item-class-1" <?php } 
                if($i == 3) {
                ?>class="item-class-2" <?php } 
                if($i == 2) {
                ?>class="item-class-3" <?php } 
                if($i == 4) {
                ?>class="item-class-3" <?php } 
                if($i == 5) {
                ?>class="item-class-1" <?php } 
            ?>>

                <div class="text-container">
                    <h1><?php  echo $description ?></h1>
                    <p><?php  echo $date = $page->getCollectionDatePublic('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></a>
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that instead of using $i as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` you actually would like `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5` and so on?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'd like to do!
Sorry, I'm in a bit over my head!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra loop, you can use the [modulo operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (aka, the remainder of a division) and some basic math to cope with the fact that you want to cycle 1->5:

```
$i= 0;   // note that I removed the "i;" at the end of this line!
foreach ($pages as $page):
   $cyclici = ($i % 5) + 1;
   // then, use $cyclici everywhere you want to see that 1-5 1-5 pattern
   ...
   if($cyclici == 1) {
   ...

   // and increment $i at the *end* of the loop instead of the start.
   $i++
endforeach;
```

EDITed to clarify the relationship between $i and $cyclici - $i is still incremented for each iteration of the loop, $cyclici is derived from that incrementing value to obtain the desired `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...` sequence.

Comment: This did it! Thanks very much! (no need to clarify) :)

Comment: I think the clarification can still help future visitors, so I'll leave it in place.  Glad I could help you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$i= 0;
$classes = array(1 => 1, 2 => 3, 3 => 2, 4 => 3, 5 => 1);
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $i++;
  .....
  echo 'class="item-class-'.$classes[$i % (count($classes) + 1)];    
  .....
}
```